# Azure Mobile WebService & Windows Phones 8.1 - can't do CRUD operations

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I've been fighting this problem for a long time and I have no idea what to do - I am trying to create some tables and mobile service to work with them. However it's not working at all. I've tried to debug the service, but when i put a breakpoint and watch the item that I get from the mobile app, then the item's properties have "**Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized.**" as values. I've found how to manage this error - but only if you have a local app, I've no idea how to do that in Azure web service. Does anyone know what to do with this problem in azure?

Thank You very much in advance for Your help and sorry if my quiestion is somewhat unclear - I am fighting with that service for really long time and I'm really lost.

Best regards,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

Do you see anything in the logs? To see the logs directly in Visual Studio, use the Service Explorer and go under the Azure tab, then Mobile Services, then right click on your service and select View Logs.

You may also want to try the new DB initializers -- that could easily be the issue. For details, see the blog [Fresh Updates to Azure Mobile Services .NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/07/fresh-updates-to-azure-mobile-services-net.aspx)

Henrik

Comment: Hi, thanks for Your reply. There are no logs - only that something was moved to another directory. Seed() method is not really what I need - I put a breakpoint in the controller's post method, and it doesn't show me the parameters values.